# Trying to increase values in database tables using SQL "cases"

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database

Honestly I'm not even sure if I should be using cases here.

I am working with ASP.net to build a website. The page I'm currently working on is a .cshtml page:

I have to score a survey of predictions *after* users have submitted them. Meaning - once the actual results come in, I score each user based on the number of predictions they got correct. Users submit predictions every week (10 survey questions per week), then I as an Admin go in and score their "quiz" based on the actual answers. Each question they get correct should add some points to their score (some questions might be worth more points than others).

User answers are stored in a db table called "WeeklyPredictions" and their score should be saved in a db table called "Scores." Both tables contain the user ID as an attribute. Both tables also have this ID *and* the week number as the primary key.

I began with this code- The 2 cases for Question1 would need be copied for all 10 questions. The variable @Q1 is the actual (Admin) answer saved as a var. Basically I just want to add some amount to weeklyScore and totalScore for each correct user prediction.

```
var selectCommand = ("SELECT * " +
    "CASE WHEN Question1 = @Q1 THEN " +
    "UPDATE Scores SET weeklyScore = weeklyScore + 1" +
    "CASE WHEN Q1 = @Q1 THEN " +
    "UPDATE Scores SET totalScore = totalScore + 1" +
    "FROM WeeklyPredictions " +
    "WHERE WeekNumber = @weeknumber" +
    "NATURAL JOIN Scores");
```

The schemas to WeeklyPredictions and Scores are:

WeeklyPredictions(Id, WeekNumber, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8, Question9, Question10)

Scores(Id, WeekNumber, weeklyScore, totalScore)

Comment: You're mixing select with update.  Do you want to extract information from your table, or update data in your table?

Comment: Not only that, but your case construct is missing the keyword `end`.

Comment: I want to update data in the Scores table, but thought I needed to use select in order to natural join the WeeklyPrediction table and the Scores table. I'm not sure how else I could add value onto attributes in the Scores table if I don't have this kind of access to what's saved for every user's quiz answers in the WeeklyPrediction table

Comment: @DanBracuk yes, I realized that. I have never used cases before and really just finished constructing this command based more on psuedocode so others could understand what I was trying to accomplish